# Can't list messages in azure query

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

i'm currently working on a messaging app, I have multiple rows in my azure table each with a message column and user id column, what i'm trying to do is load all messages that have a corresponding user id matching what is being looked for by the app, here is my current code:

```
messageTable = await MobileService.GetTable<MessageTable>().Where(item => item.User_ID == "specified id").ToEnumerableAsync();

            foreach(var item in messageTable){

                idList.Add(item.User_ID);

            }

            Debug.WriteLine(idList);
```

This is meant to get all ids matching the one being searched for and print them as a list, but it crashes, how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: `but it crashes`, Exception / StackTrace?

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple rows in my azure table each with a message column and user id column, what i'm trying to do is load all messages that have a corresponding user id matching what is being looked for by the app.

If you are talking about the relationship, I assumed that you are using the C# backend. For this approach, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135487/how-to-pull-data-with-paramter-using-azure-offline-sync/49143823#49143823). And you could use fiddler to capture the network traces when executing your query, and you could set `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always` in your backend code to capture the detailed error, details you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635018/how-did-i-messed-up-my-azure-mobile-app-server-zumo-book-sample/44642928#44642928).

Moreover, you could enable [Azure App Service diagnostics](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log.md) for capturing the exception to narrow down this issue.

In summary, you need to troubleshoot this issue and the above approach is used to make sure your mobile backend could work as expected. If you could successfully retrieve the `messageTable`, then you need to debug your mobile client to verify your client code.